# Lifting of residue field is unramified under certain setting?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

[image]

This is Lang's Algebraic Number Theory ChII prop. 10, where $K$ is assumed to be a complete field under a discrete valuation. $A\subset K$ a Dedekind ring, $\mathfrak{p}$ a maximal ideal of $A$ while $\mathfrak{P},\mathfrak{P}_u$ are respective prime ideal in integral closure of $A$.

I don't quite see why the extension circled in red lift to a nontrivial unramified extension of $E_u$ if we assume $[B/\mathfrak{P}:B_u/\mathfrak{P}_u]>1$.

Thanks in advance for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Take $b\in B/\mathfrak{P}, \not \in B_u/\mathfrak{P}_u$ and **separable over $ B_u/\mathfrak{P}_u$**,
let $f_u\in B_u/\mathfrak{P}_u[x]_{monic}$ be its minimal polynomial, take $f\in B_u[x]_{monic}$ such that $f\equiv f_u$.

Then $E_u[x]/(f)$ is an unramified extension of $E_u$.

The point is that $K$ is complete for a discrete valuation. This implies that $E_u$ is complete as well for the unique extension of the discrete valuation. This implies (Hensel lemma) that $f$ has a root in $E$ so that $E_u[x]/(f)$ is a subfield of $E$.

> The asumption that $b$ is separable is needed to apply Hensel lemma, I'm not sure what we'll get without it.